# Make jar file from folder

Tags: java, linux

i have a  folder on my desktop named theme.I am new to Linux totally.
So what do I do to create a jar file from this folder?
I found this example but It doesn't work for me.

> jar -cvf theme.jar

Comment: Make sure the directory is located in a place you can access it in linux. The desktop path could have spaces in directory names making it difficult.

Comment: Take a look at [Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) for more details

Comment: What does "doesn't work for me" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are failing to specify the input files for the jar.

Navigate to the theme/ directory using the `cd` command in Terminal.  If you want to include everything in this directory in your jar file, use the following command.

`jar cvf theme *`

Note that the `*` character (wildcard) indicates you want to include all files and subdirectories.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: You probably ment `jar`, not `java -jar`

Comment: Edited. You are correct.  Also, OP should note that there is no "-" before the `cvf` in this command.

Comment: `jar` will accept options with or without the "-" before them.

Answer (score 0):

Jar files are really just `zip` files, renamed to `.jar`. Just use any folder zipping tool (such as the `zip` command).

```
zip -r theme.jar /path/to/desktop/theme
```

Comment: That won't create a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file in the jar. If you already have one in the directory, this will work, otherwise it's better to just use the `jar` command.

Comment: @DavidConrad True. I just assumed that OP's `theme` folder contained the necessary materials for a complete `jar`, because it didn't sound like the issue was with gathering the appropriate files.